# struggle print outside the loop a not string list in a for loop and if loop

Tags: python, loops

I have this list `bravo_uncode_message=[(0000000),(0000001),(0000010),(0000011), ...]`in a for loop inside an if statement inside a for loop and I cant get it out of that 3 loops, I have tried this commands `bravo_uncode_message.extend` and `bravo_uncode_message.append` but none seems to work

```
import binascii
response=raw_input("Decrypt a message or encrypt a message? D/E : ")
if response== "E":
    message_to_encrypt=raw_input("Introduce message to encrypt: ")
    key= raw_input("Insert key:")
    abc=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    if any(word in key for word in abc):
        print 'Not a valid key...'
    elif len(key)!= 7:
        print 'Invalid key'
    else:
        key=key*len(message_to_encrypt)
        binary_message = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message_to_encrypt), 16))
        print binary_message
        binary_message= list(binary_message)
        del binary_message[0]
        print binary_message
        del binary_message[0]
        recovery_number = binary_message[0]
        print binary_message
        del binary_message[8 - 1::8]
        print binary_message
        binary_message = ''.join(map(str,binary_message))
        print binary_message
        print key
        a = binary_message
        b = key
        xored_message= int(a,2) ^ int(b,2)
        print bin(xored_message)[2:].zfill(len(a))
        print message_to_encrypt
elif response== "D":
    encrypted_message = raw_input("Introduce message to decrypt: ")
    beta_uncode_message = [tuple(map(int, format(i, '07b'))) for i in range(128)]
    g=len(encrypted_message)/7
    n=0
    for i in beta_uncode_message:
        n=n+1
        if n<129:
            alpha_uncode_message=beta_uncode_message[n-1]*g
            x=tuple(map(str,alpha_uncode_message))
            alpha_uncode_message=x
            a=encrypted_message
            b=alpha_uncode_message
            b=''.join(map(str,b))
            charlie_uncode_message = int(a, 2) ^ int(b, 2)
            bravo_uncode_message=bin(charlie_uncode_message)[2:].zfill(len(a))
            new_list = []
            q = 7
            for start_index in range(0, len(bravo_uncode_message),q):
                new_list.extend(bravo_uncode_message[start_index:start_index + q])
                new_list.append('0')
            bravo_uncode_message[:-1]
            bravo_uncode_message = ''.join(map(str, bravo_uncode_message))
            binary_axis = '0b'
            bravo_uncode_message = binary_axis + bravo_uncode_message
            bravo_uncode_message.extend(bravo_uncode_message)
            k = int(bravo_uncode_message, 2)
            uncode_message = binascii.unhexlify('%x' % k)
            print uncode_message
            if n>129:
                break
        else:
            break
    print bravo_uncode_message
```

The error I get is `AttributeError: 'str' Object has no attribute 'extend'`

Comment: your if statement doesn't have any condition? did you not get an error for that?

Comment: It has but i didn't think that was necessarily to write it

Comment: it is necessary. please post your complete code sample. otherwise the code won't compile

Comment: it is `if n<129`

Comment: And what is `beta_beta_uncode_message`?

Comment: Okey wait a second please

Comment: An other list when i post the hole code you will understand it all

Comment: The question is not clear and it does not provide any insights to other readers of stackoverflow. Please consider rewriting your question and post your complete code.

Comment: there is my whole code

Comment: my elif part is the one that its annoying me

Answer (score 0):

you redefined `bravo_uncode_message` type from `list` to `str` and then you called `extend()` on it. `extend()` is a method for `list` not for `str`.

```
bravo_uncode_message = ''.join(map(str, bravo_uncode_message))
binary_axis = '0b'
bravo_uncode_message = binary_axis + bravo_uncode_message
bravo_uncode_message.extend(bravo_uncode_message)
```

Also you also redefined `b` type from `tuple` to `str` which might be problematic in the future.

```
b=alpha_uncode_message
b=''.join(map(str,b))
```

Hope this helps. and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, but how I can get out bravo_uncode_message?  that was the metod that i have tried

Comment: sorry I don't get what you meant by "get out"? `bravo_uncode_message` is a `str` not a loop.

Comment: That outside the loop i can print the data that i have store in bravo_uncode_message

Comment: Allow me to explain, I have a problem using`bravo_uncode_message[:-1]` when I run the code that operation deletes the last character but also deletes  half of the data so I thought that if manage to extract the list bravo_uncode_message the loop wont interfiere with this operation `bravo_uncode_message[:-1]`

Comment: I don't see `bravo_uncode_message[:-1]` in your code. it should return you bravo_uncode_message back without the last character. I am not sure I get what you mean by "delete half of your data". Also Are you talking about this loop `for start_index in range(0, len(bravo_uncode_message),q):`?  It will be helpful if you provide an example for me.

Comment: Yes! that loop, the only thing that i want is that delete the last character and well as you know when i print it must show 128 strings but it dosent only shows me 65 strings

Comment: ahhh I see. so for every item in `bravo_uncode_message` delete the last character?

Comment: Yes! but when i ran `[:-1]`deletes half of my strings

Comment: ok but `bravo_uncode_message=[(0000000),(0000001),(0000010),(0000011)` contains str or integer? because python 3 prevent integer with leading 0s

Comment: are you sure `bravo_uncode_message=[(0000000),(0000001),(0000010),(0000011‌)` looks like that? have you tried printing it out? which line of the code stored this value?

Comment: 0000000  0000001  0000010 like this but in vertical